# Why doesn't TypeScript complain about an array's type when built from concat?

Tags: arrays, typescript, interface, concatenation

In the following code, I expect the TypeScript compiler to fail on both `getThings_concat` and `getThings_nocats` but it only complains about the latter:

```
interface IThing {
    name: string;
}
function things1() {
    return [
        {name: 'bob'},
        {name: 'sal'},
    ]
}
function things2() {
    return [
        {garbage: 'man'},
    ]
}
function getThings_concat():Array<IThing> {
    return <Array<IThing>>([].concat(things1(), things2()));
}
function getThings_nocats():Array<IThing> {
    let ret:Array<IThing> = [];
    things1().forEach(thing => {
        ret.push(thing);
    });
    things2().forEach(thing => {
        ret.push(thing);
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Here's the one compiler error, though I'd expect two errors (one for each `getThings_*` function):

```
test.ts(24,18): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ garbage: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IThing'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ garbage: string; }'.
```

What can I change in `getThings_concat` so that I can use `[].concat` but have it complain when `things2()` returns non `IThing`s?

Comment: Why are you writing `[].concat` ? `concat` does not mutate the original array; you can safely write `things1().concat(things2())`. Or just write `[...things1(), ...things2()]`.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I don't like `things1().concat(things2())` for readability (it makes `things1` seem special.  That last one is much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the error you expect, by changing the type of `[]` from `any[]` to `IThing[]`:

```
function getThings_concat():Array<IThing> {
    return (<IThing[]>[]).concat(things1(), things2());
}
```

However it'd be much better to simply write the function this way, which doesn't require any type assertions

```
function getThings_concat2():Array<IThing> {
    return [...things1(), ...things2()];
}
```

Comment: Okay, I thought I was changing the type of `[]` but now I see that I was perhaps just casting the result of the concat?  Anyway, that last syntax is better.  Thank you!